# How to make a realistic cave in Blender for a VR game? (Blender -> Unity)

Tags: game-engine, resolution

At my workplace I got the task to create a huge cave, one that looks similar to Batman's cave, in Blender, to later be used in Unity. I am stuck as I have never done anything like this before.
What is the correct way of doing this? What are the steps and what do I need? I cannot even start the project.
I have donwloaded a rock brushset and tried it out but it was way too high resolution for a VR game. When I was looking at tutorials they were all about creating a high resolution scene but not for game development.
Here are some references I got:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi :). There's a detailed BlenderGuru tutorial for that [How to Make a Cave with Blender](https://youtu.be/1J4r0mt9zz0)

Comment: And a useful [Reddit thread about mountains with tunnels](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/78httx/can_you_sculpt_mountains_with_tunnels_in_blender/)

Comment: Thank you! I actually saw the BlenderGuru one but it is too high resolution for a game so I was looking for a way that goes around it maybe with retopology or textures :(

Answer (score 3):

A fun way is to use the built-in [A.N.T. Landscape addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/ant_landscape.html)
No need for any sculpting ;)

1. Add two mountains (i used Volcano and Default presets)
2. Scale and Boolean one of them to make a cave
3. Done

<sup>A cross-section preview of the result.</sup>
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way in the end to make it low-res enough for a game but still be as realistic as possible?

Comment: Dupliacte the mesh, decimate one of them using the decimate modifier, bake normals from the hi-res mesh to the low one using cycles bake: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html

Comment: lol...love the lazy solutions! +1

Answer (score 2):

Create a very simple version of your object, like a half sphere, give it object a *Displace* modifier in order to create chaotic relief:

[image]

You can also sculpt:

[image]

To add chaos, in *Edit* mode you can select all and *Mesh > Transform > Randomize*, or enable the *Proportional Editing > Random* option and move some vertices.

You can keep a low-poly version, displace or sculpt a high-poly version and bake the normals of the high-poly onto the low-poly.

As for the texture, you can unwrap your object, create a black texture then use a rock texture as *Stencil*. Once done you can use a b&w version of your image as height map to fake the relief. Texture will allow you to fake a high resolution object when your object remains actually low-poly. You can also use procedural texture even though it may not look as realistic as rock photos:

[image]

Comment: +1 but how can i do that with geometry nodes? 

Comment: Oh it's easy, Just ask Chris!!

Comment: i asked him - he said he would write an own answer.... :D

Comment: + I've heard Chris was actually Batman so who better than him?

Comment: yeah...but i heard too he killed Moon....Superman in a fight.... :D

Comment: That's what I let people believe, my come back will be epic

Comment: Well…I just saw it  Batman saved you with a few other guys…you came back…but a bit weird…

Answer (score 1):

Of course - a batman cave is worthless without stalactites...

so with this easy little node setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

you get this:

[image]

the good thing with geometry nodes: you can adapt your cave as you need it:

so e.g. you can change the entrance:

[image]

you can change the look of your cage:

[image]

and of course you can adapt the distribution of your stalactites:

[image]

[image]

Batmobile by Fr3akShow: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/batmobile-1989-1b951b22db35419a890ee3a2923a2185

Comment: Nice, but I can't see the Batmobile?

Comment: open your eyes man. There it is! :D

Comment: wow, plus it looks like a chocolate cave, I hope Batman won't end up overweight

Comment: Damn. That hurts. How did you know I have problems with my weight…?!

Comment: well, look at your cave, it looks more like a chocolate truffle, I've just unmasked you, you're not Batman, you are Chocolateman

Comment: Damn....now everybody knows....